# Looping through an array and making a request call to an API doesnt resolve in react native with async/await keywords

Tags: javascript, react-native, loops, async-await, axios

when i try to make a request to my API like this:

```
export default ({ navigation }) => {
// call getMovieImages with the id of the likedMovies from the state.likedMovies

const { getMovieImages, state:{ likedMovies }} = useContext(MovieContext);
   likedMovies.map(async (item, index) => {
      const data = await getMovieImages(likedMovies[index]) 
      console.log(data)
   })
   return (
  <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
   <Text>You liked {likedMovies.length} movies!</Text>
   <View style={styles.navBar}>
    .
    .
    .
   </View>
  </SafeAreaView>
   )
}
```

I am getting a console log of undefined even though I've used an async keyword before the map function. Can anybody tell me why is this happening?

Also, I have checked the `likedMovies[index]`. It outputs the ids of the liked elements in the array. So, no problem on there as well. Should I just use the `.then()` statement?

By the way, I have checked all the types and the API requirements. It all fits. Waiting for your thoughts on this, thanks.

***likedMovies is an array of integers, and the getMovieImages dynamically makes API requests with the integers coming from the likedMovies array in this example. However, even though the map function loops through the indexes and finds the relevant id values of the movies, getMovieImages doesn't resolve, and the data object logs undefined to console.***

I will try to separate the images field into two objects for liked and non-liked movies' images in my state object but actually, I try to refrain from such DRY practises, so any other solution would be very much appreciated. Thanks for your time!

Comment: I have solved the issue, but in a completely different way than what @AbdulHaseeb proposed. Had to go over multiple files. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `async await` inside a `map` which returns a promise for each iteration.
If you do it like below

```
const data = Promise.all( likedMovies.map((item, index) => {
           return getMovieImages(likedMovies[index]) }));
```

It will return an array generated from the results of each iteration

Comment: Is calling the function on componentDidMount a solution?

Comment: it did not resolve again by the way. I dont know why.